# Comparison of Nvidia Waveglow model with WaveNet both based on Google's Deepvoice for text-to-speech synthesis

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I've spent a lot of time trying to understand the [Google's WaveNet work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.03499.pdf) (also used in their DeepVoice model), but am confused when comparing it to Nvidia's WaveGlow model. I'm referring to [this Tensorflow implementation of Wavenet.](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2/blob/master/wavenet_vocoder/models/wavenet.py)

[Nvidia claims it's faster](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/generate-natural-sounding-speech-from-text-in-real-time/) (also [[here]](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/resources/nvidia:tacotron_2_and_waveglow_for_pytorch/performance))than WaveNet and that's why they use it:

> WaveGlow combines insights from Glow5 and WaveNet6 in order to provide
>   fast, efficient and high-quality audio synthesis, without the need for
>   auto-regression.

But when I print out the WaveGlow model, the number of parameters is **~270 Million.**
For Wavenet, it's only **~3Million**, so Waveglow is **100X bigger model.**

1. Why do they claim that it's faster?
2. Is there any way to compare the #of ops in both models?
3. How can the total ops be less in Waveglow when the model is 100X bigger?